# hover li and second li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu and it has before psuedo if I hover my li element I want to change properties of current li and after than li element
[image]

```css
.cruise-turlari .cruise-box .cruise-list-box ul li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 86%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1px;
  background: #cbcbcb;
}
.cruise-turlari .cruise-box .cruise-list-box ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 7px 33px;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.4s;
  transition: all linear 0.4s;
}
.cruise-turlari .cruise-box .cruise-list-box ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="cruise-list-box">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Vizesiz Yunan Adaları İzmir Hareket <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Vizesiz Yunan Adaları İstanbul Hareket <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Vizesiz Yunan Adaları  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ege &amp; Adriyatik  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Akdeniz &amp; Adriyatik  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Baltık Başkentleri  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Kuzey Avrupa &amp; Akdeniz  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Fiyordlar  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Akdeniz  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Kanarya Adaları <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[and click to real demo](http://firatabak.com/test/cruise-anasayfa.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: now is it clarify ? my english is not well to tell sorry about that

Comment: Not really, no. What is it you are trying to remove / add? Any Demo should be in a Stack Snippet or JSfiddle...not an actual page.

Comment: I have navigation list (li) and my li has -:before psuedo- if I hover Ii I want to remove propeties of -before psuedo- at the same time I want to remove  second li -before psuedo-

Comment: this is just like tongue twister ;-)

Comment: each li has psuedo (before) and properties of the psuedo is height:1px;background:#blabla.. and I want to display:none hover li and next li is ist clearify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
.cruise-turlari .cruise-box .cruise-list-box ul li:hover:before, .cruise-turlari .cruise-box .cruise-list-box ul li:hover + li:before {
  height: 1px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

So you use the adjacent sibling selector on the hover too.

Comment: yes exactly this is the thing that I want thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you add a special class

```
.cruise-list-box ul li.special:after {
    height: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

then, using jQuery, add events on mouseover and mouseleave

```
$('li').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('special');
});
$('li').mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('special');
});
```